# Repeated measures in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, statistics, modeling

I'm analyzing some data that I was given, it is set up as follows:

- 2 sites
- 30 trees in each site (tree is nested in site)
- 12 branches per tree (a branch from each direction - N,S,E,W in each of crown level - Up, Mid, Low) (repeated measure)
- Dependent variable is shoot damage from an insect (proportion of shoots damaged per branch)

The goal is to determine if insect damage varies within a tree (from the data we see no effect of cardinal direction and a clear effect of crown level)

I want to model these data using MCMCglmm, I've I nested tree in site by coding it as follows (where DF is my data frame):

```
 DF$Tr<-Df$Site:Df$Tree
```

My MCMCglmm model is as follows:

```
prior1 = list(R = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002), G = list(G1 = list(V =  1, nu = 0.002)))

Fit1<-MCMCglmm(cbind(Damage,No.dam) ~ Crown+Dir+Site, random = ~Tr, family="multinomial2", prior = prior1, data=DF,verbose=F)
```

I'm confused on how to specify the repeated measures in the model. I think I need to use
     `rcov~units`  or 
     `rcov~idh(Tr):units`

However, I'm not exactly sure which is correct (or I could be completely off track altogether). I'm a graduate student so I'm still learning stats and there is nobody in my department that works with these types of models and I'm finding it difficult to find the help I need.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar problem, but haven't solved it yet. I found this: http://hlplab.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/multinomial-random-effects-models-in-r/ and this paper by Hadfield: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i02/paper ... neither one has totally answered my question, unfortunately. But I'm working on the answer and will update here and would appreciate if you'd do the same!

Answer (score 0):

1. For starters, if I understand well your experiment description, the branches are repeated not only the trees. Therefore, I would put the branch ID as a random variable to account for repeated measurements, not the tree IDs.
2. <s>If you setup the binary outcome has two separate traits (two columns with cbind), your distribution type should be "multinomial2".</s>

[This article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.5098&rep=rep1&type=pdf) might help a bit in understanding how to model binary outcomes with MCMCglmm. If you have more questions about modelling (i.e., statistics) and not how the MCMCglmm works, you might get better answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

About `rcov`:
I think that what is confusing is that GLMM is used to deal with correlation of residuals in repeated measurements. Thus, it feels natural to want to put the repeated variable in the var-covariance matrix of the residuals but actually the covariance is already dealt with by using the repeated measurement grouping term as a random factor. Therefore, the default `rcov = units` should be fine.

Comment: 1. There are no repeated measures per branch, each branch has one measure so there is no measurable branch effect (12 branches per tree, with one measurement per branch).   2. If you look at the code provided I have used family = "multinomial2". The question is about how to structure `rcov` in a repeated measures MCMCglmm.

Comment: @Sara About the first point, you might want to clarify it in your question because you have the mention "(repeated measure)" at the branch level that is confusing... About the second point, I indeed got confuse with another post I was responding to. Sorry, I will update my answer. I will also update my answer to address more specifically the `rcov` structure.